# How to get a cartesian product form a set of a set

Tags: c++

My goal was to get cartesian products for, AxB,CxB, (AxB)xC. I've done the others but I'm confused on how to get (AxB)xC. This is my thought in code so far, _A,_B,_C,setAxB are already populated properly with random numbers. This code isn't complete but I am not sure what else to do for this function.

```
void defineSetABC1(vector<pair<int, pair< int, int>>> &setABxC, vector<pair<int, int>> &setAxB, vector<int> &_B, vector<int> &_A,vector<int> &_C){
    cout << "(A x B) x C is now calculated" << endl;
    
    for(int i=0;i<setAxB.size();i++)
       {
           for(int j=0;j<_C.size();j++)
           {
               pair < int, int> item;
               pair<int, pair< int, int> > q;

               
               setABxC.push_back();
           }
       }
 
    
};
```

This is how I did the others,

```
void defineSetAxB(vector<pair<int, int>> &setAxB, vector<int> &_A, vector<int> &_B){   
cout << "Set AxB is now calculated" << endl;
        
        for(int i=0; i<_A.size();i++){ //_A
            for(int j=0; j<_B.size();j++){ //_B
                pair < int, int> item;
                item.first = _A.at(i);
                item.second = _B.at(j);
                setAxB.push_back(item);
       
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Do it in two steps. First calculate AxB. Then use the same algorithm to multiply the result with C. You know how to multiply two things. So multiply twice.

Comment: Thank you for the edit you provided.  This clarifies what you were struggling with and demonstrates that you have really tried (and partially succeeded).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can write a general cartesian product function and then apply it twice. Once to compute AxB and again to compute (AxB)xC.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<class T, class U>
vector<pair<T,U>> cartesianProduct(const vector<T> &lhs, const vector<U> &rhs) {
    vector<pair<T,U>> result;
    for (const T& x : lhs) {
        for (const U& y : rhs) {
            result.emplace_back(x, y);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Example usage

```cpp
int main()
{
    vector<int> a = {1,2};
    vector<int> b = {3,4};
    vector<int> c = {5,6};
    
    vector<pair<int, int>> axb = cartesianProduct(a, b);
    vector<pair<pair<int, int>, int>> abxc = cartesianProduct(axb, c);

    for (const pair<pair<int, int>, int>& i : abxc) {
        std::cout << "((" << i.first.first << ", " << i.first.second << "), " << i.second << ")" << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

which prints

```
((1, 3), 5)
((1, 3), 6)
((1, 4), 5)
((1, 4), 6)
((2, 3), 5)
((2, 3), 6)
((2, 4), 5)
((2, 4), 6)
```

Comment: This is a very nice one :-)  I'm not sure however that OP is already very comfortable with templates, considering his/her current struggles with the problem ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It's about cartesian products, so tuples and tuples of tuples, and it can be confusing indeed. Since this seems to be schoolwork,  I'll not provide a perfect solution such as [jodag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75421725/3723423)'s but will try to improve you own, step by step.

### Preliminary remark

Some simplifications are possible in your existing AxB code. The loop body could for example be compacted into:

```
          pair < int, int> item(_A[i],_B[j]);
          setAxB.push_back(item);
```

or even the following, which frees you somewhat of having to think too much about the types of the objects you put in a pair:

```
          setAxB.push_back(make_pair(_A[i],_B[j]));
```

### Implementing your combined cartesian product

**First step:** call your existing implementation of `defineSetAxB()` because you already wrote it:

```
defineSetAxB(setAxB, _A, _B);
```

**Second step:** Apply exactly the same algorithm between the intermediary result in `SetAxB` and `_C` as you previously did when combining `_A` and `_B`, just that for the first tuple element you won't have an `int` but a `pair`. This is easier if you've simplified your code according to my preliminary remark:

```
for(int i=0; i<setAxB.size();i++){ // like for _A
    for(int j=0; j<_C.size();j++){ // like for _B
        setABxC.push_back(make_pair(setAxB[i],_C[j]));
    }
}
```

This will not compile, because your parameter type does not correspond to the requirements. If AxB is a vector of pairs of ints, then (AxB)xC will be a vector or pairs of pairs of ints and ints.  Or in short,  the first parameter of your function shall be redefined as:  `vector<pair<pair<int, int>,int>> &setABxC`.  That changed, everything will work fine.

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/TwAdxD)

### Other improvements

I don't know if the signature of the functions are imposed in your homework.  But I'd at least make a distinction between input and output parameters using `const`, avoid unnecessary `_` prefixes. For example:

```
void defineSetAxB(vector<pair<int, int>> &setAxB, const vector<int> &A, 
                                                  const vector<int> &B){
```

If you have more freedom, you should not impose the caller of your function to provide an intermediary object for your calculations. so `SetAxB` in `SetABxC1` should not be a parameter but a local variable.

Last but not the least, you may consider returning the result vector instead of requesting the caller to provide it by reference.  This would prevent surprises when those objects are not empty).